# Fire animation only once, ani js scrollreveal

Tags: html, css, animation, animate.css

I'm using anijs to animate some content on my website when scrolling
http://anijs.github.io/

this is my code:

```
data-anijs="if: scroll, on: window, do: bounceInLeft animated, before: scrollReveal, after: removeAnim"
```

this animation should fire only once if the page is loaded

this should take care of that

```
after: removeAnim
```

but it's not working, the animation fires every time I scroll up and down

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ran into the same problem. Using holdAnimClass worked.

source: [Hold animation after function](https://github.com/anijs/anijs/wiki/Hold-animation-after-function)

usage: `after: holdAnimClass`

Answer (score 1):

had the same prob, animations re-running every time i scroll - didn't have anijs-helper-scrollreveal.js included in the page. added it and that solved the problem in my case